# ReplaceAll(""","") not working android

Tags: java

Is there a way to replace special character when using `ReplaceAll().` for example `ReplaceAll(""","")` is not working android

Comment: define not working ... i'm pretty sure that this code will not get compiled ... and if so, you should read some java books

Comment: The problem is that """ is not correctly interpretated, you must use a escape code for """.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `"` is a meta character,It works when you escape the special character.

```
s = s.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

[oracle docs on the same](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html)

Answer (score 3):

Escape the meta character `"` with "\" :

```
string.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Remember to assign it back to the String reference , because it returns a new String object.

Look at the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) class to understand how to construct the regex.

Answer (score 3):

Use this, `\"` represent the  `"`

```
 String s = yourString.replaceAll("\"","");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the next sentence

```
    replaceAll("\"","");
```

you must use \ for escape ".

Answer (score 2):

You should use `replace()` instead:

```
str = str.replace("\"", "");
```

`replaceAll()` is used for replacing regular expressions.